# NullPointerException ao tentar montar uma Activity para mostrar um vídeo

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Meu código:

```
public class VideoActivity3 extends Activity {

    public final static String LOCATION3 = "com.compdigitec.VideoActivity3.location3";
    public final static String mFilePath = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View main = View.inflate(this, R.layout.ijkplayer, null);
        setContentView(main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mFilePath = intent.getExtras().getString(LOCATION3);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        PlayerView player = new PlayerView(this)
                .setTitle("")
                .setScaleType(PlayStateParams.fitparent)
                .hideMenu(true)
                .hideSteam(true)
                .setForbidDoulbeUp(true)
                .hideCenterPlayer(true)
                .hideControlPanl(true);

        player.setPlaySource(mFilePath, true)
                .startPlay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

Estou recebendo esta saída de erro:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                      at tv.lycam.ijkplayer.widget.PlayerView.<init>(PlayerView.java:577)
                      at org.tech.android.TechMedia.VideoActivity3$override.onResume(VideoActivity3.java:32)
                      at org.tech.android.TechMedia.VideoActivity3$override.access$dispatch(VideoActivity3.java)
```

Este erro é produzido nesta linha, ao iniciar o player:

```
PlayerView player = new PlayerView(this)
```

A classe `PlayerView` vem daqui: https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/blob/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/java/tv/lycam/ijkplayer/widget/PlayerView.java

No meu XML eu incluo isso:

```xml
<include layout="@layout/simple_player_view_player"/>
```

Esse layout vem daqui: https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/blob/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/res/layout/simple_player_view_player.xml

Comment: Free, nesse seu código não tem nenhum lugar definindo o método setVisibility(). Coloque o código em que você está realmente usando método.

Comment: @AckLay É dentro do construtor do `PlayerView` que deu a exceção, classe essa que não é dele, e sim de algo que ele importou.

Comment: settingsContainer = activity.findViewById(ResourceUtils.getResourceIdByName(mContext, "id", "simple_player_settings_container"));
        settingsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Isso dentro do PlayerView, que estou importando de um aar...

Comment: De onde você achou essa classe `PlayerView`? Onde é que ela está?

Comment: A classe PlayerView pode ser vista neste link [https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/raw/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/java/tv/lycam/ijkplayer/widget/PlayerView.java] @VictorStafusa

Comment: @VictorStafusa mas aí fica difícil o7 hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O link da classe `ViewPlayer` é esse: https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/raw/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/java/tv/lycam/ijkplayer/widget/PlayerView.java

A linha 577 é uma linha em branco, e portanto você deve estar usando alguma versão diferente. Entretanto, no construtor da classe temos isso:

```
        settingsContainer = activity.findViewById(ResourceUtils.getResourceIdByName(mContext, "id", "simple_player_settings_container"));
        settingsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

A linha com o `setVisiblity` dá o `NullPointerException`, e portanto o `settingsContainer` é `null`.

Para o `settingsContainer` ser `null`, é porque o método `findViewById` falhou. Esse método falhou provavelmente porque o `ResourceUtils.getResourceIdByName` falhou.

O código de `ResourceUtils` está aqui: https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/raw/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/java/tv/lycam/ijkplayer/utils/ResourceUtils.java

Eis o código do método em questão:

```
    public static int getResourceIdByName(Context context, String className, String name) {
        int id = 0;
        if (context == null) {
            return id;
        } else {
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();

            try {
                String var10 = packageName + ".R$" + className;
                Class desireClass = Class.forName(var10);
                if (desireClass != null) {
                    id = desireClass.getField(name).getInt(desireClass);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException var7) {
                Logger.e("ClassNotFoundException: class=%s fieldname=%s", className, name);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var8) {
                Logger.e("IllegalArgumentException: class=%s fieldname=%s", className, name);
            } catch (SecurityException var9) {
                Logger.e("SecurityException: class=%s fieldname=%s", className, name);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException var101) {
                Logger.e("IllegalAccessException: class=%s fieldname=%s", className, name);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException var11) {
                Logger.e("NoSuchFieldException: class=%s fieldname=%s", className, name);
            }

            return id;
        }
    }
```

Este método deve ter retornado 0 porque o campo `simple_player_settings_container` da classe `R.id` do pacote da sua `VideoActivity3` não foi encontrado.

Entretanto, ele está tentando acessar o conteúdo do arquivo de layout https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/blob/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/res/layout/simple_player_view_player.xml - Ou seja, ele está buscando o arquivo de layout errado.

É importante notar que a classe `tv.lycam.ijkplayer.widget.IjkVideoView` é a que renderirza o vídeo. Mas ela renderiza somente o vídeo e mais nada. Já a classe `tv.lycam.ijkplayer.widget.PlayerView` é a responsável por renderizar o vídeo junto. Pelo menos pelo que eu entendi do código, é isso, mas posso estar errado.

Assim sendo, a `IjkVideoView` precisa da `PlayerView` para funcionar. Entretanto, o `PlayerView` já inclui o `IjkVideoView` no seu layout.

No seu XML de layout você tem isso:

```xml
<include layout="@layout/simple_player_view_player"/>
```

Isso não vai dar certo. O que você quer é isso:

```xml
<tv.lycam.ijkplayer.widget.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

O código da sua `VideoActivity3` também vai ter que ter algumas alterações:

```
public class VideoActivity3 extends Activity {

    public final static String LOCATION3 = "com.compdigitec.VideoActivity3.location3";
    public final static String mFilePath = "";

    private PlayerView player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        player = (PlayerView) View.inflate(this, R.layout.player, null);
        setContentView(main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mFilePath = intent.getExtras().getString(LOCATION3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        player.setTitle("")
                .setScaleType(PlayStateParams.fitparent)
                .hideMenu(true)
                .hideSteam(true)
                .setForbidDoulbeUp(true)
                .hideCenterPlayer(true)
                .hideControlPanl(true)
                .setPlaySource(mFilePath, true)
                .startPlay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Uma coisa que ainda vai estar pendente é acerca desses textos *hardcoded* no `simple_player_view_player.xml`:

- "`您正在使用移动网络播放视频\n可能产生较高流量费用`" deve ser trocado por "`Você está executando\no vídeo usando a rede móvel.\nIsso pode acarretar maiores\ncustos de tráfego de dados.`"
- "`继续`" deve ser trocado por "`Play`", "`Rodar`" ou "`Executar`".

Acredito que haja duas formas para trocar esses textos por seus equivalentes em português:

1. No final do método `onCreate` da sua `VideoActivity3`, coloque isso:

   ```
   LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(ResourceUtils.getResourceIdByName(player, "id", "app_video_netTie"));

   ((TextView) a.getChildAt(0)).setText("Você está executando\no vídeo usando a rede móvel.\nIsso pode acarretar maiores\ncustos de tráfego de dados.");
   ((TextView) a.getChildAt(1)).setText("Rodar");
   ```
2. Outra forma é desempacotar o AAR, alterá-los para trocar os textos em chinês por português e então reempacotá-los.

Comment: Esse projeto no link parece estar hospedado em algum tipo de github chinês! será?! hue

Comment: @AckLay Aparentemente é isso mesmo. Uma versão ching-ling do github.

Comment: É sim, eheh. veja: https://coding.net/u/lycam

Comment: Obrigado @VictorStafusa, no layout ligado a este contexto eu incluo  <include layout="@layout/simple_player_view_player"/>, e nesse layout dele existe o simple_player_settings_container tanto que o mesmo chega ate a ser renderizado pelo android studio na visualização.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, aqui esta o layout....  https://coding.net/u/lycam/p/lycamplus-android-ijkplayer-sdk/git/blob/master/sdk/LycamPlayer/ijkplayer/src/main/res/layout/simple_player_view_player.xml

Comment: @FreeFlix Você pode editar a sua pergunta para colocar lá como está o sseu arquivo de layout?

Comment: @FreeFlix Editei a resposta. Veja se agora funciona.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim deu certo, muito obrigado...

Comment: @FreeFlix Se essa resposta resolveu teu problema, poderia então marcá-la como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ que tem lá em cima abaixo dos números de votação? Ao fazer isso, você também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida/solucionada. Obrigado.

Comment: Feito @VictorStafusa, obrigado..